# Firebase-based application does not work globally

Tags: java, android, firebase, region

Firebase-based application does not work globally, but it works locally. How can I solve the problem. In other countries, registration to the FireBase database is not possible.

What can I do in the firebase area in the code section so it can be used in other countries?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.morixsoft.restaurant&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Use TunnelBear app to change your country IP and pass registration in firebase

Comment: The application is mine. What can I do in the firebase area in the code section so it can be used in other countries?